# CountIf results in "0"

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I need help for one part of my complete code. The code below should count the rows that meet the defined conditions for every month. The problem is that I only get "0" as result. I cant figure out why? Is it maybe because of my date format? My source wb contains dates in a format like "01.01.2019".

The code should also only count rows from the first of any month. Meaning: 01.01., 01.02.,01.03. etc.

My master workbook(wb) has an user form with file explorer function, where I can choose my source workbook(wbSource) and apply the macro on it. As seen in the complete code below.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim x As Long


For x = 1 To 12

    ws.Cells(8, 1 + x) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), Format(x, "00") & "." & MonthName(x), _
        wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 50)

    ws.Cells(9, 1 + x) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), Format(x, "00") & "." & MonthName(x), _
        wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 50, wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 100)

    ws.Cells(10, 1 + x) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), Format(x, "00") & "." & MonthName(x), _
        wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 100)

Next x
```

**Complete Code**

```
  Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' update averages

         Const YEAR = 2019

        ' open source workbook
        Dim fname As String, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
        fname = Me.TextBox1.Text

        If Len(fname) = 0 Then
           MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
           Exit Sub
        End If

        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True) ' no link update, read only
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to suit

        Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table 2") '

        ' scan down source workbook calc average
        Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long
        Dim sMth As String, iMth As Long
        Dim count(12) As Long, sum(12) As Long

        lastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For iRow = 1 To lastRow

            If IsDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) _
                And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then

                iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))   ' col H
                sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30) ' Col AD
                count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1 '

            End If
        Next


   ' counting the rows  


    Dim x As Long


    For x = 1 To 12

        ws.Cells(8, 1 + x) = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), Format(x, "00") & "." & MonthName(x), _
            wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 50)

        ws.Cells(9, 1 + x) = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), Format(x, "00") & "." & MonthName(x), _
            wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 50, wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 100)

        ws.Cells(10, 1 + x) = _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), Format(x, "00") & "." & MonthName(x), _
            wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 100)

    Next x




        ' close source worbook no save
        wbSource.Close False

        ' update Table 2 with averages
        With ws.Range("A3")
        For iMth = 1 To 12
            .Offset(0, iMth - 1) = MonthName(iMth) & " " & YEAR
            If count(iMth) > 0 Then
                .Offset(1, iMth - 1) = sum(iMth) / count(iMth)
                .Offset(1, iMth - 1).NumberFormat = "0.0"
            End If
        Next
        End With




        Dim msg As String
        msg = iRow - 1 & " rows scanned in " & TextBox1.Text
        MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Table 2 updated"





    End Sub
```

[image]

**Result-Sheet in Wb** - as you see there are only zeroes displayed in the number of rows table

[image]

**Example of wb.Source -** Columns H(8) and AD(30) are the only relevant one for the ounting of the rows. In the example belows the last row should not be counted as the date does not match the condition ( its not the first of the month).

[image]

Comment: Please advise what kind of dates you have in WsSource.columns(8).  Select one of the cells and set the format to "General". If the cell's value changes to a number you have "true dates" if it doesn't change you have "date strings".

Comment: Hi, the cell value changed to a random number.

Comment: @PlutoX What is the formula you would use on the worksheet to accomplish this? Does it return the expected value?  Offhand, I would be using a different worksheet function to do that calculation.

Comment: I've updated my post with the complete code. What I'm trying to do basically is calculating the avarage value based on  a set of conditions and counting rows based on a set of conditions of the source wb. This is done via a file explorer user form, where I choose the source wb and trigger the calculation with a command button - see screenshot. The avarage value part is working. All I need now is the countif function to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is from the way you handle the dates. Your data has true dates. They aren't random numbers but a count of days since Jan 1, 1900. They uniquely identify every day for the past 120 years, and the system will continue to identify every day for the next 120 years, too. I believe the code below will do, more or less, what you intended to do.

```
Sub WriteCountIf()
    ' 025

    ' The YearCell must contain a year number like 2019.
    Const YearCell As String = "A1" 'change to suit

    Dim DateRng     As Range        ' the range to search for  dates in
    Dim DaysRng     As Range        ' the range to search for  days in
    Dim StartDate   As Date         ' first day to include in count
    Dim EndDate     As Date         ' last day to include in count
    Dim C           As Long         ' the column to write to (= month)

    With ActiveSheet                ' better to define the sheet by name

        ' make sure your result range doesn't overlap the search ranges
        Set DateRng = .Range(.Cells(11, 8), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
        Set DaysRng = .Range(.Cells(11, 30), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 30).End(xlUp))

        For C = 1 To 12
            StartDate = DateSerial(.Range(YearCell).Value, C, 1)
            EndDate = DateSerial(Year(StartDate), C + 1, 0)
            .Cells(8, 1 + C).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                                     CountIfs(DateRng, ">=" & StartDate, _
                                              DateRng, "<=" & EndDate, _
                                              DaysRng, "<=" & 50)

            .Cells(9, 1 + C).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                                     CountIfs(DateRng, ">=" & StartDate, _
                                              DateRng, "<=" & EndDate, _
                                              DaysRng, ">" & 50, _
                                              DaysRng, "<=" & 100)

            .Cells(10, 1 + C).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                                     CountIfs(DateRng, ">=" & StartDate, _
                                              DateRng, "<=" & EndDate, _
                                              DaysRng, ">" & 100)
        Next C
    End With
End Sub
```

It seems that your data only show day and month. That's a matter of display (cell formatting). The underlying dates include the year. Therefore you need a year when you search them. I have added a year in A1. You can move that cell to anywhere or hard-program a year into the code.

Your definition of search ranges, just by columns, is insufficient, and it overlaps with the cells into which you want to write the counts. I have assumed a start row and my code finds the end of each column. Please try it out.

Comment: Thank your for the feedback! Could you somehow implement your code-snipped in my already existing complete code? I'm kinda failing at it right now. The date column has also a year in it. As I mentioned above,  I'm trying to  calculate the avarage value based on a set of conditions and counting rows based on a set of conditions of the source wb. This is done via a file explorer user form, where I choose the source wb and trigger the calculation with a command button - see screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below the counting procedure is converted into a function that returns its result as an array. This is called by the main procedure and written to the worksheet. I couldn't test the code en total but the part described above works as advertised.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' update averages

    ' "Year" is the name of a VBA function.
    ' To use the same word here as a variable name is asking for trouble.
    Const Year As Integer = 2019

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim Wb As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim fname As String

    fname = Me.TextBox1.Text
    If Len(fname) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("Table 2") '

    ' open source workbook
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True)   ' no link update, read only
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")            ' change to suit

    Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sMth As String, iMth As Long
    Dim count(12) As Long, sum(12) As Long              ' Confusing: Count is a VBA method

    ' scan down source workbook calc average
        ' observe how .Rows.count is written with lower case c
        ' because of your declaration of "count" in that way
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow
        If IsDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) And _
           IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then

            iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))       ' col H
            sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30) ' Col AD
            count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1
        End If
    Next    

    ' counting the rows
    Ws.Cells(8, 2).Resize(3, 12).Value = RowsCount(Year, wsSource)
    ' close source worbook no save
    wbSource.Close False

    ' update Table 2 with averages
    With Ws.Range("A3")
        For iMth = 1 To 12
            .Offset(0, iMth - 1) = MonthName(iMth) & " " & Year
            If count(iMth) > 0 Then
                .Offset(1, iMth - 1) = sum(iMth) / count(iMth)
                .Offset(1, iMth - 1).NumberFormat = "0.0"
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Dim msg As String
    msg = iRow - 1 & " rows scanned in " & TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Table 2 updated"
End Sub

Private Function RowsCount(ByVal RefYear As Integer, _
                           Ws As Worksheet) As Variant
    ' 025

    Dim Fun         As Variant      ' Function return value
    Dim DateRng     As Range        ' the range to search for  dates in
    Dim DaysRng     As Range        ' the range to search for  days in
    Dim StartDate   As Date         ' first day to include in count
    Dim EndDate     As Date         ' last day to include in count
    Dim C           As Long         ' the column to write to (= month)

    With Ws
        ' make sure your result range doesn't overlap the search ranges
        Set DateRng = .Range(.Cells(11, 8), .Cells(.Rows.count, 8).End(xlUp))
        Set DaysRng = .Range(.Cells(11, 30), .Cells(.Rows.count, 30).End(xlUp))
    End With

    ReDim Fun(1 To 3, 1 To 12)
    For C = 1 To 12
        StartDate = DateSerial(RefYear, C, 1)
        EndDate = DateSerial(Year(StartDate), C + 1, 0)

        Fun(1, C) = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                                 CountIfs(DateRng, ">=" & StartDate, _
                                          DateRng, "<=" & EndDate, _
                                          DaysRng, "<=" & 50)

        Fun(2, C) = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                                 CountIfs(DateRng, ">=" & StartDate, _
                                          DateRng, "<=" & EndDate, _
                                          DaysRng, ">" & 50, _
                                          DaysRng, "<=" & 100)

        Fun(3, C) = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                                 CountIfs(DateRng, ">=" & StartDate, _
                                          DateRng, "<=" & EndDate, _
                                          DaysRng, ">" & 100)
    Next C

    RowsCount = Fun
End Function
```

Capitalization is very important in VBA. As the example of your use of the `Count` word demonstrates VBA will try to adapt to your style. Therefore, if you have no system you will destroy VBA's. The theory I follow is to use caps and smalls on all variable names. Then I type using only lower case. VBA will correct my typing and this serves as a spell checker, helping to avoid typos. There are a few exceptions to this but that's the general rule I follow.

It's the same with the choice of variable names. Generally I avoid using words VBA uses. That prevents confusion for me (never mind VBA). But if I do use VBA's words I follow the existing capitalization.

Comment: The count results still in "0" - see new screenshot in post. I'm not sure if the private function RowsCount is counting the correct workbook? It should count the rows in wb.Source and enter the value in Wb. I've updated my post with the result screen from Wb and  a row example from wb.Source. I hope this will help...

Comment: Aah! That's my fault. Sorry about that. In my test I used column 1 instead of 30. The corrected line reads like this: `Set DaysRng = .Range(.Cells(11, 30), .Cells(.Rows.count, 30).End(xlUp))`. I have modified it in the code above, too. Please try again.

Comment: I get an error message: "Unable to get the CountIfs property of the WorksheetFunction class". And it points to the Fun(1, C) = Application.WorksheetFunction with the CountIfs.

Comment: Set a break on that line and check the values of `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Check the value of `RefYear`, too. And while you're busy in that corner, also check if the ranges `DateRng` and `DaysRng` are set correctly. They start in row 11 for a reason that doesn't apply to WsSource. Perhaps your WsSource doesn't have 11 rows?

Comment: startdate = 01.01.2019, enddate = 31.01.2019, refyear = 2019

But just to clarify - I only need rows which have the first day of a month as date in column H.  Meaning: only 01.01, 01.02, 01.03, 01.04 etc. everything else should be ignored, as mentioned in my initial post.

Comment: First, let's get the code to run. Then we'll check if it works correctly. Since the dates appear correct, what about the ranges? If the ranges are correct and the dates obviously are, then the CPOUNTIFS should work, too.

Comment: You're right, DateRng and DaysRng doesn't show anything. Range(.Cells(11, 8) - so what does the 11 represents? the number of rows?  My source wb is huge, has over 14k rows.I appreciate your help.

Comment: One more thing: Im not sure what DaysRange is for? It is referring to column 30, right? But in column 30 I have my numerical values as seen in the screenshots. The conditions to be fulfilled by the rows are a combination of the date (column 8) and the numerical value(column 30).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213683/discussion-between-variatus-and-plutox).